# CLLocationCoordinate2D array populated from Firebase doesn't keep it's entries. Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

I'm having a problem with `alertNotificationCoordinatesArray` that stores `CLLocationCoordinates2D from retrieving posts from Firebase. Oddly the array gets populated every time I enter`NewMapViewController`. I thought that it would stay populated and only get new entries as the child observer send a new post from Firebase, but instead it's retrieving the posts every time`NewMapViewController`loads.
My problem is, that I get to`NewMapViewController`eighter from a menu or from a notification action button.
In the second case I use`alertNotificationCoordinatesArray`in the`checkAlerts2`function so I need it to be already populated but it's empty.

here is the interested part of the code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        mapView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
//        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true  //for getting user location in background mode as well

        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow   //map following user


//        let globalLocationManager: GlobalLocationManager
        configureLocationServices()
        addDoubleTap() // enabling duble tap gesture recognizer
//        mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true


        let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate

        if location == nil {
            return
        }

        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location!, 1000, 1000) // set mapView based on user location coordinates
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        centerMapOnLocation()

        // alerts coordinates to post to Firebase
//        let alertDrawLatitude =  alertDrawCoordinates?.latitude    // not used ?
//        let alertDrawLomgitude = alertDrawCoordinates?.longitude   // not used ?
//        let title: String? = alertNotificationType                 // not used ?
//        var subtitle: String? = alertNotificationType              // not used ?

        //  user alert notification. takes coordinates from alertNotificationArray( populated with firebase returning coordinate for all alerts

         displayAlerts()

        print("alertNotificationCoordinatesArray at loading NewMapViewController is\(alertNotificationCoordinatesArray)")

        // if coming from alert notification
        if NewMapViewController.checkCounter > 0 {
            checkAlerts2()
        } else { return }


    }
```

the function that uses the Firebase posts:

```
func displayAlerts() { 

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Community").child("Alert Notifications").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            //            defer { self.dummyFunctionToFoolFirebaseObservers() }
            guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }
            guard let firebaseKey = snapshot.key as? String else { return }
            //                let date = data!["Date"]
            //                let time = data!["Time"]
            let dataLatitude = data["Latitude"]!
            let dataLongitude = data["Longitude"]!

            let type = data["Description"]!
            let id = Int(data["Id"]!)
            let doubledLatitude = Double(dataLatitude)
            let doubledLongitude = Double(dataLongitude)
            let recombinedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: doubledLatitude!, longitude: doubledLongitude!)

            print("Firebase alerts posts retrieved")

//            print("Longitude Actual DataKey is \(String(describing: firebaseKey))")

//            print("fir long \((snapshot.value!, snapshot.key))")
            let userAlertAnnotation = UserAlert(type: type, coordinate: recombinedCoordinate, firebaseKey: firebaseKey, title: type,id: id!)
            self.userAlertNotificationArray.append(userAlertAnnotation)  // array of notifications coming from Firebase
            print("userAlertNotificationArray after retrieving from Firebase is : \(self.userAlertNotificationArray)")

            self.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray.append(recombinedCoordinate) // array for checkig alerts on route
             print("alertNotificationCoordinatesArray after retrieving from Firebase is : \(self.alertNotificationCoordinatesArray)")
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(userAlertAnnotation)

        })
    }
```

and the prints from console:

```
alertNotificationCoordinatesArray at loading NewMapViewController is[]
Firebase alerts posts retrieved
userAlertNotificationArray after retrieving from Firebase is : [<fix_it_mapView.UserAlert: 0x1599f2e60>]
alertNotificationCoordinatesArray after retrieving from Firebase is : [__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.50139585197814, longitude: 11.335974854073397)]
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.50139585197814, longitude: 11.335974854073397)
```

How can I fix this array that gets emptied?

Comment: Since `alertNotificationCoordinatesArray` gets emptied whenever you return to this view, it makes me think the view is redefining a new property. Where is `alertNotificationCoordinatesArray` defined? Is it a property of your class? Do you have a `viewDidAppear(_:)` function in this class?

Comment: @guard working else panic. `alertNotificationCoordinatesArray` is defined in the `NewMapViewController`class, and it doesn't have a `viewDidApear()`function . what should I change to make it keep the values?

Comment: Can you show the line where `alertNotificationCoordinatesArray` is defined? If it's a property of `NewMapViewController` it would be lost when the view is dismissed. Also, I would check to see how many times `viewDidLoad()` is being called during the app's life cycle. It could be setting multiple observers by calling `displayAlerts()` every time the view loads.

Comment: @guard working else panic. I see. Being a property of`NewMapViewController it gets emptied or just instantiated multiples times?
`viewDidLoad()`gets called Avery time I get to `NewMapViewController`. How would I check it?
should I call`displayAlerts`from a `viewVillApear()`instead?

Comment: Right, if you want `alertNotificationCoordinatesArray` to persist after `NewMapViewController` has been dismissed and presented again, it needs to be kept somewhere else like a [model class](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/DefineYourDataModel.html).

Comment: I would also move `displayAlerts()` somewhere that will only be called once per app launch. Like in the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function in the `AppDelegate`

Comment: I added it in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function in the AppDelegate as `NewMapViewController().displayAlerts()` but I get `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`error..
is it so bad to call that function every time I load the `NewMapViewController` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184773/discussion-between-guard-working-else-panic-and-vincenzo).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @guard working else panic to point out that my array gets emptied every time I leave the VC, so the solutions to simply put it in a struct on a separate swift file.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation



struct MapArray {
    static var alertNotificationCoordinatesArray: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []  //  alert notification array coordinates only used to draw alerts on map and find route obstacles
}
```